# Get current document with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which, when you click on the icon, displays a text field and a button, used for searching. The displayed content is basically an HTML document called from the manifest like this:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
 }
```

Now, the question is how can I access the current document loaded in the browser, using javascript? Because I want to extract the question from the text field and then go and find the answer in the current document.

Thank you!

**EDIT1:**

Code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "SmartSearch",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Smart Search extension for Google Chrome.",
  "content_scripts": 
  [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["smartsearch.js"]
  }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

}
```

smartsearch.js

```
SmartSearch() = function (){

    var x = document.title;
    alert(x);
}
window.onload = SmartSearch;
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Smart Search</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="smartsearch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Smart Search</p>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="search_text_field"></input>
      <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

For now, all I want to do is to display the title of the current loaded page when I press on the extension icon, just to check if I have acces to the DOM. The problem is that I get the title of the popup. What's the solution?

**EDIT2:**
I see that if I go to a page, the alert with the title of the page does appear when it loades (there are some exceptions, like youtube page), but I want to do that when I press the icon of the extension.

Comment: use content scripts for all DOM actions.

Comment: could you, please, be more specific, because this is my first time dealing with chrome extensions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) wich you can declare on your manifest like this:

```
  {
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Where `matches` is the domain in which you are going to be using the script. That way the css and js are inside the document itself. But if you need to send data from the document to your plugin, you need to use [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). Here you have an example of how you can send a message from the content script to the plugin.

```
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
  });
```

And then you have to use `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` to recive the message. Example:

```
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
          console.log(sender.tab ?
              "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
              "from the extension");
          if (request.greeting == "hello")
              sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

On the other hand if you want to send a Message from the plugin to the content script you have to use.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

And the same as before `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` to recive the message on the other side.

[This](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) is a very good resource for getting started.

**EDIT: A working example of the initialization of the content_scripts**

Manifiest:

```
    {
    "name": "Intervention",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/**"],
      "js": ["action.js"]
    }

   ],

  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

JS

```
var element = document.title;
alert(element);
```

Comment: what if I want to use the script on any page, not a specific one?

Comment: You can declare all using "matches": ["*"],

Comment: Remember that the user, at the time of install your plugin is going to be warned about you asking for permission to use the plug in in all the sites he visits. You can also declare multiple specific sites.

Comment: Small correction it has to be `"matches":"<all_urls>"` instead of `"matches": ["*"]`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction... This could save him some trouble.

Comment: I've put this in manifest, after the browser action: "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": "<all_urls>",
    "js": ["smartsearch.js"]
  }
  ]...somewhere else I've seen that now I can write alert(document.title) to get the title of the current document, but for me it returns the name of the popup...

Comment: I've edited the post with a working example of what you are trying.

Comment: and using the code from above for this page, you get "google chrome - Get current document with Javascript - Stack Overflow" as a result? because if you get it, it means that I'm doing something wrong, because I don't...

Comment: Ok, if you you already achieve to load the content script, now you have start using messages if you want communication to happen between content-script and background . It's a bit more complicated, but you have all the documentation you need in my post, use those links and the example code. You need to expend some time understanding the concepts and then you should get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) on the pages and use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to interact between your extension and tabs.

The content script gets a request from your extension, does the computation on the page (you'll have access to the DOM so you should be able to do anything on the page).

The content script will then send a response back to your extension which you can display in the popup.